# How to apply filters in DynamoDB in DAO layer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I used this method to get data from dynamodb. But how i can apply filters or (Where clause to get data by name and address)

public class CustomerDAO extends AbstractDAO implements DynamodbDAO {

```
@Override
public Class<Customer> getClazz() {
    return Customer.class;
}
public List<Customer> getByUserId(String userId) {

        return getDynamoDB().scan(
                getClazz(),
                new DynamoDBScanExpression().withFilterExpression(
                        "USER_ID = :userId")
                        .addExpressionAttributeValuesEntry(":userId",
                                new AttributeValue().withS(userId)));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have CustomerID as Primary partition key. Should I need to define primary sort key for filters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a [FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-FilterExpression) to your scan.  Using this expression, you can apply filtering logic to any attribute on each item, described further [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#FilteringResults).  This filtering is applied server side by DynamoDB so only the results that match will be returned to you, but you still "pay" for the read IO it took to fetch the data.

On a related matter, scanning a DynamoDB table should typically be avoided.  It requires reading every single item in the table and unless your table is very small you will incur a large amount of read IO and it will take a long time to return.  You should try to accomplish your queries by using a hash or range key that allows you to directly get to the data you want.  If this cannot apply to the primary hash/range key of the table you should look into creating global secondary indexes to allow you to access the data you want directly.